# Error in AOT cleanup loader, failed to build Angular App with AOT mode

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, angular2-aot

After hearing so much about the Angular AOT mode, I thought to give it a try. So, we migrated our app to Angular v4.1.2 with all the necessary changes that were required. When I was trying to run the build with AOT mode with the following part of ngc-webpack plugin configurations inside my webpack config file, I am stuck at some unknown error.

```
new ngcWebpack.NgcWebpackPlugin({
        disabled: !AOT,
        tsConfig: helpers.root('tsconfig.webpack.json')
      }),
```

My tsconfig.webpack.json file is as follows :-

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    some ts configs
    ....
    ....
     ...
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2015"
    ],
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@angular/*": ["node_modules/@angular/*"]
    },

    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "types": [
      "hammerjs",
      "node",
      "jasmine",
      "lodash",
      "source-map",
      "uglify-js",
      "webpack"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist",
    "src/**/*.spec.ts",
    "src/**/*.e2e.ts"
  ],
  "awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
    "forkChecker": true,
    "useWebpackText": true
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "genDir": "./compiled",
    "skipMetadataEmit": true
  },
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "buildOnSave": false,
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": false
  }
}
```

When I run the build, after 94% of completion, and successfull compile with awesome typescript loader, the aot-clean-compiles comes into action and throws a big stacktrace like below comes in :-

```
ERROR in ./src/app/applications/xxx.component.ts
Module build failed: TypeError: refactor.program.getTypeChecker(...).getTypeFromTypeNode is not a function
    at _ctorParameterFromTypeReference (/Users/xxx/sources/migration/yyy/node_modules/src/aot-clean-transformer/loader/text-based-loader/loader.ts:57:58)
    at /Users/xxx/sources/migration/bm_dashbaord/node_modules/src/aot-clean-transformer/loader/text-based-loader/loader.ts:123:12
    at Array.map (native)
    at _addCtorParameters (/Users/xxx/sources/migration/bm_dashbaord/node_modules/src/aot-clean-transformer/loader/text-based-loader/loader.ts:122:46)
    at /Users/xxx/sources/migration/bm_dashbaord/node_modules/src/aot-clean-transformer/loader/text-based-loader/loader.ts:154:11
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at _removeDecorators (/Users/xxx/sources/migration/bm_dashbaord/node_modules/src/aot-clean-transformer/loader/text-based-loader/loader.ts:147:6)
    at Object.aotCleanLoader (/Users/xxx/sources/migration/bm_dashbaord/node_modules/src/aot-clean-transformer/loader/text-based-loader/loader.ts:303:7)
```

I am stuck on this error for quite a while now and unable to figure out what is the thing I am doing wrong. Please someone help me out here.

Comment: Which typescript version are you using?

Comment: Apparantely, I realized someone has downgraded the typescript version, so I upgraded it to 2.2.2 and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the version is 2.2.2, it shouldn't throw this error for this version.